# Why POST method doesn't work when I add this script?

Tags: php, phpmailer, http-response-codes

I'm using PHP Mailer and when I added the following script to my HTML code, the $_POST method doesn't retrieve any value from the input fields. And when I remove, it works normally.

```
<script>
$(document.forms[0]).submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $.get('mail.php', function(data) {
  document.getElementById("Success").style.visibility = 'visible';
  });
});
</script>
```

I'm just using it to keep the user on the same page after submit and then show a success message.

At the end of the PHP code I'm using this:

```
$mail->Body= $body;

if(!$mail ->send()){
    echo "Error";
    echo $mail ->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    http_response_code(200);
}

?>
```

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense. Your JS doesn't check the response value, and your PHP code doesn't look at the request params, so nothing is going to work. I suggest you look at the JS example provided with PHPMailer.

Comment: You're making a `GET` request, so there will never be anything in `$_POST`.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between `$.get` and `$.post`?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you do is prevent the browser from making the POST request it would have made if you didn't include the script.

> ```
> event.preventDefault();
> ```

---

The second thing you do is make an (ajax) GET request instead (which can't have the body you are trying to read).

> ```
> $.get('mail.php'
> ```